# Pyqt5 item of first column in currentrow QTableview doesn't return correct value

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a two column tableview and I want to get the item in the first column of the currently selected row.

[This image shows my  problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSOEX.png)

Here is the code snippet:

```
    def shotselected(self):
    try:
        selectedRowIndex = self.tableWidget_shotselect.currentRow()
        print ("Selected row index: " + str(selectedRowIndex))
        item = self.tableWidget_shotselect.itemAt(selectedRowIndex, 0)
        print (item.text())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Even entering a manual int indexes to itemAt() doesn't result in the correct cell value being printed.

Comment: `item = self.tableWidget_shotselect.item(selectedRowIndex, 0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itemAt(x, y)` returns the item that covers the *pixel* (x, y) in the widget's coordinate system.

`item(row, col)` returns the item at row, col in the widget's grid system.